# How does one write an automated integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I read a lot about unit testing and integration testing, and the unit testing part I understand fairly well - isolate the object under test, and mock out dependencies using interfaces and inject those. (Or use seams to inject testable behavior).

However something that is still a mystery to me even after searching is integration testing. Every blog and link talks about testing various components together, do's and dont's, CI Servers, etc, but there's not much explanation in the way of how this is to be done.

Is an integration test automated? Or is this a manual effort? If it is automated, do I write this as code in the native language my app is in? How do I check or verify if the integration test is working as expected?

For example, if I have 4 services (a Socket Client, a Socket Server, a Database, and a Web Application) and I want to do some integration testing on how these 4 services interact with each other. How exactly how would I approach this? I know that some dummy data will be involved, but which part of my integration test is checking if the systems are working together correctly? This part is really unclear to me.

Comment: yes integration test is automated,  basically you have to automate the manual process involved to complete a functionality, for example if I have to create a test for login functionality I would automate all steps I need to perform to log in manually from `opening my browser` to `hitting the login button` did you gave a look to `selenium` that is mostly used as frontend integration testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said about unit testing, you need to isolate the object under test, and mock out dependencies using interfaces and inject those...

Integration test is without isolating the unit... You can test two part or more (but you shouldn't have extensive integration test suits neither big test scenario). An example of integration test is testing your code with the database, you could need for that to initiate the database and clean it to have a repeatable tests.

You could have as well interface test (client execution and integration with the server for example) and so on.

Don't forget that this tests come with a downside, they are slower and harder to maintain, but they have different purpose than unit test, which is checking that units works as expected with real dependencies.

So to wrap-up if you write a test without totally isolating the unit it is an integration test, due to its nature it's better to test the logic of your code by unit test and reserve fewer integration tests when needed to test the interaction between the units.

You can also check this nice introduction https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48237/what-is-an-integration-test-exactly

An interesting definition from "the pragmatic programmer": integration tests show that the major parts of a system work well together

Comment: What is responsible for verifying / asserting that the integration is correct? Ie. I could write a 'unit test' using the current API I am using to open a connection to a database, invoke my controller and confirm the controller returned the model using asserts, but is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: You could implement an integration test with the same tool as unit testing... xUnit will do it. The difference is not technical but conceptual, in one case you test behavior in isolation the other you test interaction...